# Counting frequency of element in a list and joining them

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of list. I want to obtain the frequency of element in the inner list and concatenate that with the element in the outer list.

```
aa =['a', ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd']]
```

I try to use Counter to get the frequency of occurrence of each element in the inner list as :

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(aa[1])
```

It gives:

```
Counter({'b': 4, 'd': 2})
```

I want to concatenate this with the outer list element and obtain as follows:

```
'ab4d2'
```

I can also iterate through the Counter and get key, value in a list:

```
y = []
for k, v in surr.items():
    y.append(str(k) + str(v))

Output: ['O4', 'Sb2']
```

There are many answers to get the frequency of occurrence but I did not find any which does this (the problem is joining with outer 'a' in an efficient way) . Could anyone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression with `str.join`:

```
aa[0] + ''.join('%s%d' % t for t in Counter(aa[1]).items())
```

Given `aa = ['a', ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd']]`, this returns:

```
ab4d2
```